# ASP.NET MVC using Url.Content with dynamic images

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I create a dynamic url to display an image?

I am creating a web page that lists search results of products and their associated images.

I tried using Url.Content, but it does not format the url correctly.

Code I created:

```
<img src="../../Images/<%: product.PicFileName %>" alt="photo" />
```

Html that was output:

`<img src=".. ..="" Images="" nopic.jpg="" alt="photo"  ="">`

I also tried creating a helper method but it created the exact same output:

```
public static string GetPicUrl(string picFileName)
    {
        string picUrl = "../../" + picFileName;

        return picUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this:

`<img src="<%: Url.Content("/Images/" + filename) %>" alt="foo" />`

where `filename` = "foo.jpg" and it gives me
`<img src="/Images/foo.jpg" alt="foo"/>` which links to http://hostname/Images/foo.jpg

Please let us know what format you want the Url in if this isn't what you had in mind and I will try to help you some more.